# How do I get pbutils on Ubuntu 18.04 and 19.04, a required dependency of gstreamer?

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, dependencies, 19.04, gstreamer

I have the following build error:

```
meson.build:49:0: ERROR:  Dependency "gstreamer-pbutils-1.0" not found
```

I want to meet needed dependencies. the previous one was:

```
meson.build:48:0: ERROR:  Dependency "gstreamer-1.0" not found
```

but that was fixed with [gstreamer's own webpage and instructions](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-linux.html?gi-language=c#install-gstreamer-on-ubuntu-or-debian).

however I cannot find any way to install gstreamer-pbutils-1.0.

The [gstreamer page on pbutils](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gst-plugins-base-pbutils-1.0/gstpbutils.html?gi-language=c#pbutils-page) is not very helpful. It seems they assume pbutils utils would ship with the instructions they gave.

I am on Ubuntu 19.04.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visit https://packages.ubuntu.com next time first.

For current query see two relevant search results for your question -  [`gstreamer-pbutils-1.0.pc`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=disco&section=all&arch=amd64&keywords=gstreamer-pbutils-1.0.pc&searchon=contents) and for [`gstreamer-1.0.pc`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=disco&section=all&arch=amd64&keywords=gstreamer-1.0.pc&searchon=contents).

So you need to install two development packages with needed `pkg-config` files:

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev libgstreamer1.0-dev
```

---

If you want to build GStreamer by yourself you may be also interested with installing full list of its dependencies with:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep gstreamer1.0
```

and then do what you want to do.